# How can I create a function that takes another function as a parameter with an unknown number of arguments?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm creating an `onClick` function. The premise is that when a button is clicked, It will call a function like so:

```
// This connects the callback to the button class method named "something"
something.onClick(&callback, "a string", 123);

// This is called when the button is clicked
callback("a string", 123);
```

I'm already using a function pointer to call the function `callback`, however I don't know how to accept a variable number of arguments. The API I want is exactly like I specified above: the first parameter is the function, and each subsequent parameter is an argument to be passed. So far I've thought about using boost::bind, but am unable to figure out how that will fit in with what I'm attempting.

Comment: Are you storing the callback or just calling it in `onClick` and discarding it when `onClick` is done?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm storing it in a class and then calling it when the button click occurs. This is how I'm storing it: `void(*onClickFunction)() = nullptr;`

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a way to do that.  You're storage needs to have a defined type and there is no type that I know of that will store a function of any amount of parameters.

Comment: @styphNate not really identical in case you mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698790/why-am-i-receiving-a-segmentation-fault-when-calling-a-stored-function-pointer). That one was asking to fix code without giving enough context/mcve. This one something else

Answer (score 1):

You can just capture the supplied arguments in a lambda. This can't be stored in a function pointer, so use `std::function`

```
class Something
{
public:
    template <typename Func, typename ... Args
    void onClick(Func&& func, Args&& ... args)
    {
        m_onClick = [=]{ func(args...); };
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> m_onClick;
    // call m_onClick somewhere
};

int main () {
    Something something;
    something.onClick(&callback, "a string", 123);
}
```

Comment: I get this error when doing something.onClick(&callback, ""): 

undefined reference to `void GuiButton::onClick<void (*)(), char const (&) [1]>(void (*&&)(), char const (&) [1])'

Answer (score 0):

How would you call the function if you dont know how many parameters it has? There are solutions for that, but why not keep it simple...

Lets say you want to use either one of the two as callback:

```
void foo(std::string x) {}
void bar(int x) {}
```

Then you can wrap them together with the parameters in a lambda and store it in a `std::function` like that:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void foo(std::string x) {}
void bar(int x) {}

struct caller {
    std::function<void()> callback;
    void call() { callback(); }
};

int main(){
    caller c{ [](){ foo("test"); }};
    c.call();
    caller d{ [](){ bar(1); }};
    d.call();
}
```

If the parameters to be passed are supposed to be more dynamic you need something more of course.